# Implementing Carrierwave-Direct with Devise Registration Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, devise, carrierwave, image-uploading

I have an image upload field in my Devise new user registration form that I'm currently using Carrierwave to handle. I want to upload directly to S3, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to transition to Carrierwave direct.

According to the instructions:

> You can generate a direct upload form like this:

```
class AvatarController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @uploader = User.new.avatar
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = new_user_url
end
end

<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

However, I need the image upload field to be in the same form as the Devise new user registration form instead of a separate direct_upload_form.

Is this possible?